# kendo File Upload change button using Bootstrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

In this sample can I change the button select Files to this add files with the plus sign? Can I just used this k-button class and using `Bootstrap4` class?

```
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/


https://dojo.telerik.com/@mcdevittnccn/ujOHacoM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the localization.select ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/configuration/localization.select)) value to specify the text. Then use jQuery to add the custom classes and icon.

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
  localization: {
      select: "Add Files..."
  }
});
$("#files").closest('.k-upload-button').addClass('btn btn-success'); // add the bootstrap classes
$("#files").closest('.k-upload-button').removeClass('k-button k-button-md k-rounded-md k-button-solid k-button-solid-base'); // remove the kendo classes
$("#files").closest('.k-upload-button').prepend('<span class="k-icon k-i-plus"></span>'); // add the icon
```

Example: https://dojo.telerik.com/aJaHeMOq

Comment: Can I use important in the custom css file to replace the kendo style with a new style?

Comment: You could, it’d be a bit cleaner but probably a bit more difficult to maintain in the long run.